# I cannot click on the button which is on the background of layout

Tags: android, button, webview

I am using webview in a xml layout, i am setting webview to full screen and setting it transparent programmatically, and i have also three buttons and one imageview on the same layout, all views are in a single frame Layout
the buttons are not firing click events.
the xml is:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">





<!--    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>-->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/bt_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:src="@drawable/logo_image"
                android:id="@+id/pk_estate_image"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />



            <Button
                android:layout_width="240dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="Find Your Dream Home"
                android:id="@+id/bt_find_your_dream_home"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"

                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:background="@drawable/backgroud_button"/>




            <Button
                android:layout_width="240dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="Property For Wanted"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/bt_property_for_wanted"
                android:layout_below="@id/bt_find_your_dream_home"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:background="@drawable/backgroud_button"/>





            <Button
                android:layout_width="240dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="Submit Your Property"
                android:layout_below="@id/bt_property_for_wanted"
                android:id="@+id/bt_submit_your_prooperty"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/backgroud_button"/>


        </RelativeLayout>




        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />



    </FrameLayout>


</ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and my webview setting are:

```
  mWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

how to make it clickable

[image]

[image]

Comment: add a clicklistener to the buttons, I dont see the java code but using the clicklistener is the only way to do things when  button is clicked

Comment: i have added click listener its working when i place webview on the top, but the layout is not adjusting

Answer (score 2):

You have added webview at the last this makes webview handle all the touch and click events. You need to add the webview first in framelayout and other views after that. This will bring all the views above(z-index) higher than webview and will allow them to receive the clicks.

```
 <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/bt_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_image"
        android:id="@+id/pk_estate_image"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />



    <Button
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="Find Your Dream Home"
        android:id="@+id/bt_find_your_dream_home"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"

        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/backgroud_button"/>




    <Button
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="Property For Wanted"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/bt_property_for_wanted"
        android:layout_below="@id/bt_find_your_dream_home"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:background="@drawable/backgroud_button"/>





    <Button
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="Submit Your Property"
        android:layout_below="@id/bt_property_for_wanted"
        android:id="@+id/bt_submit_your_prooperty"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/backgroud_button"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i have did it but, it disturb my layout when i click on message button on the bottom of screen, when i click on message button the layout expend to full screen from webview and all buttons will alyout disturb

Comment: what happens to layout could you add a screenshot?

Comment: trap in similar kind of situation, button not clicked in Framelayout with Listview just switch the order & its work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to change order of views in framelayout

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true">

<WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/bt_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:src="@drawable/logo_image"
                android:id="@+id/pk_estate_image"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />



            <Button
                android:layout_width="240dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="Find Your Dream Home"
                android:id="@+id/bt_find_your_dream_home"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"

                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:background="@drawable/backgroud_button"/>




            <Button
                android:layout_width="240dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="Property For Wanted"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/bt_property_for_wanted"
                android:layout_below="@id/bt_find_your_dream_home"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:background="@drawable/backgroud_button"/>





            <Button
                android:layout_width="240dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="Submit Your Property"
                android:layout_below="@id/bt_property_for_wanted"
                android:id="@+id/bt_submit_your_prooperty"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/backgroud_button"/>


        </RelativeLayout>


    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: i have changed but its distrubing my layout when i click on chat button, when i click chat button it expend to full screen and then my logo and buttons become overlay on it

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
<WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

to this:

```
<WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="false" />
```

Comment: Buttons click listeners is ok?  `Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_find_your_dream_home);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    Log.i("ax", "onClick");
    
   }
  });`

Comment: yes button click is ok,  btFindYourDreamHome = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_find_your_dream_home);   btFindYourDreamHome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent findDreamHome = new Intent(Home.this, FindYourDreamProperties.class);
                startActivity(findDreamHome);
            }
        });//end of find property button